# How to determine PCL (Point Cloud Library) version in C++ code?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

Is there any way to check PCL version in C++ code?
I need compatibility between 1.6 and 1.7 on source code level, i. e. something like this:

```
#if PCL_VERSION >= 1.7
// some tasty functionality
#else
some old replacement
#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PCL version and some other useful preprocessor macros are defined in "pcl_config.h" header file. For example, to conditionally compile some fallback code for versions lower than 1.7.2, you can write:

```
#include <pcl/pcl_config.h>

#if PCL_VERSION_COMPARE(<, 1, 7, 2)
  ... fallback code ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to see PCL version,

```
#include <pcl/pcl_config.h>
std::cout << PCL_VERSION << std::endl;
```

For example, 100901 meaning 1.9.1.

Comment: There's also PCL_VERSION_PRETTY.